# Can't start app with Fastify-Vite and Redux-toolkit

Tags: vite, redux-toolkit, fastify

I'm trying to make an app with Fastify and Vite. It works in dev mode (running `npm run dev`), but I get an error after trying to run `npm start`.

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:40
      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                                ^

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import '.../bomb-game/bomb-game/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/query' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from .../bomb-game/bomb-game/client/dist/server/index.js Did you mean to import @reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/index.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:406:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:227:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:845:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1043:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:228:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {   url: 'file:///.../bomb-game/bomb-game/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/query', code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT' }
```

In builded by Vite index.js file I have such imports:

```
import { jsx, jsxs, Fragment } from "react/jsx-runtime";
import { useSelector, useDispatch, Provider } from "react-redux";
import { useState, memo, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery, setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";
import { createAction, createReducer, combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
```

But error mentions only redux-toolkit lib.

I have tried to use node version 20, different changes in vite config, but still this error.

[Source code of the app](https://github.com/Maksim631/bomb-game)

Comment: Found this [discussion](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1960) that helped me